# Azure Stateless Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am new to `Azure Service Fabric` ( *stateless* ). I am trying to `moq` of this code

```
var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
```

but, am unable to do. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How are you doing it? What is going wrong?